# Covariance matrix as linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Why applying the covariance matrix to the original vector will turn the vector to the direction of largest variance?  How do I intuitively understand this?

And what does the inverse of the covariance matrix do? What happens when applying the inverse of covariance matrix to a vector repeatedly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been asked and answered on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/): [Covariance matrix as linear transformation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/259058).